# An array to store file id and date created

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im thinking about how I could develop an array so that It would store a file id with its created date.

What kind of array would I use?

for example the array would hold :

"fileid1" -> "20/12/12"
"fileid2" -> "20/12/13"
etc...

Could I use an assosiative array?

Comment: You'd use an object or an array of objects, there are no associative arrays in js.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are for numerically-indexed data, like lists.

For information indexed in other ways, use an object:

```
var files = {}; // <== A blank object
files[someFileId] = thatFilesDate;
files[someOtherFileId] = thatOtherFilesDate;
```

> Could I use an assosiative array?

Sounds like you're used to PHP. PHP's associative arrays are a very special, hybrid data structure: They're ordered lists of name/value pairs allowing lookup via numeric index *or* name. Highly unusual.

JavaScript, like most languages/environments, doesn't have those out of the box. (You can create them easily enough.) But 95% of the time, you don't need an *ordered* list of name/value pairs, just name/value pairs. In JavaScript, that's what an object is.